# Recursive function for a multidimensional array?

Tags: php, mysql, multidimensional-array

I am attempting to use a recursive function to search through a multidimensional array, such as the one below, to find certain values, i.e. people who went to certain school, majored in a certain subject, hold a certain job title, etc. In case your wondering, this array is output from the Facebook Graph API. In reality there are more than 3 offset arrays, depending on the number of friends a user has, it could be in the thousands.

Here's a solution I tried with very little knowledge of recursive functions (my first thought was to use in_array before I found out it didn't work for md arrays):

So to give you an idea of how the md array below works, check out this snippet of code:

```
$friend = $fqlResult[0]['name'];
echo "$friend";
```

*The output would be "BLANK" since I deleted the person's name.

```
$data = $fqlResult;
$collegemajor = (isset($value['education'][0]['concentration'][0]['name'])) ? $value['education'][0]['concentration'][0]['name'] : null ;
$major = "Business Administration";
if (isset($collegemajor)) {
    foreach($data as $key=> $value) {
          if ($value($collegemajor) == $major) {
              echo "User $key is majoring in $major";
     }
  }
}
```

So here is the multidimensional array referenced above. In this example, I want to pull the names of all of the user's friends who majored in Business Admin. in college. As you can see from this snippet, there aren't any (I think) but in the long version of the array, there are plenty. The code above produces no output and I'm lost as to how to make it work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
 Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [name] => BLANK
        [education] => 
        [work] => 
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [name] => BLANK
        [education] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [school] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => 108087985890571
                                [name] => St. Andrew's School
                            )

                        [year] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => 138383069535219
                                [name] => 2005
                            )

                        [type] => High School
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [school] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => 20697868961
                                [name] => Boston University
                            )

                        [concentration] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => Array
                                    (
                                        [id] => 108654845832522
                                        [name] => Business Administration
                                    )

                            )

                        [type] => College
                    )

                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [school] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => 108289315859633
                                [name] => University of Miami
                            )

                        [year] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => 138879996141011
                                [name] => 2013
                            )

                        [type] => Graduate School
                    )

            )

        [work] => Array
            (
            )

    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [name] => BLANK
        [education] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [school] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => 115444241803885
                                [name] => Saint Andrews High School
                            )

                        [year] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => 137616982934053
                                [name] => 2006
                            )

                        [type] => High School
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [school] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => 112033702149888
                                [name] => Boca Raton High
                            )

                        [year] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => 137616982934053
                                [name] => 2006
                            )

                        [type] => High School
                    )

                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [school] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => 108087985890571
                                [name] => St. Andrew's School
                            )

                        [type] => High School
                    )

                [3] => Array
                    (
                        [school] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => 107573562605861
                                [name] => Duke University
                            )

                        [concentration] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => Array
                                    (
                                        [id] => 104045469631213
                                        [name] => Political science
                                    )

                            )

                        [type] => College
                    )

            )

        [work] => 
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [uid] => 1234567
        [name] => BOB NO ONE
        [education] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [school] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => 106039752760627
                                [name] => Berwick Academy
                            )

                        [year] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => 137616982934053
                                [name] => 2006
                            )

                        [type] => High School
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [school] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => 108087985890571
                                [name] => St. Andrew's School
                            )

                        [type] => High School
                    )

                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [school] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => 105690226130720
                                [name] => Northeastern University
                            )

                        [concentration] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => Array
                                    (
                                        [id] => 108654845832522
                                        [name] => Business Administration
                                    )

                            )

                        [type] => College
                        [classes] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => Array
                                    (
                                        [id] => 189873264368867
                                        [name] => 2011
                                    )

                            )

                    )

            )
```

Comment: Do you want a broad recursive search, or a specific one? [e.g. If, bizarrely, someone's school was _named_ Bus.Admin., would you want them to be spit out by your search?]

Comment: As you can see above, schools and majors are assigned id's so in practice, I would most likely use the id's when searching.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's really no need for recursion for something like this, considering the depth of the tree is always fixed and the structure is known. Using some nested loops would do the trick:

```
$friends = $fqlResult;
$friends_BA = array();

foreach ($friends as $friend) {
    if (is_array($friend['education'])) {
        foreach ($friend['education'] as $school) {
            if (isset($school['concentration'])) {
                foreach ($school['concentration'] as $concentration) {
                    if (strpos(strtolower($concentration['name']), 'business') !== false) {
                        $friends_BA[] = $friend;
                        continue 3; // skip to the next friend
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

var_dump($friends_BA);
```

Comment: I'm getting a bunch of these: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\pathweavr\friendtest.php on line 93

Comment: Let me add that if you crack the code on this problem which I've been struggling with for weeks, I will seriously owe you for life.

Comment: Oops, I didn't notice that `[education]` could be `null` in some cases. I just updated the answer... try that version.

Comment: (And I just now updated it to search the `id` field instead of `name`)

Comment: We're close. It's returned three users with business admin degrees. I'm assuming the rest aren't showing up because they have more than just college listed. I'll paste a larger portion of the array above, let me know if you think that's what the problem is. I'm also getting a million: Notice: Undefined index: concentration in C:\xampp\htdocs\pathweavr\friendtest.php on line 106, 106 is if (is_array($school['concentration'])) {

Comment: If you change `is_array` to `isset`, that'll get rid of the notice.

Comment: For some reason it's only returning three users but there are 21.

Comment: Can you show me the entries that aren't being returned that *should* be returned?

Comment: Yeah the notices we're gone without me having to do that.

Comment: I can invite you to a join.me session and show you my screen?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5977/discussion-between-brianreavis-and-mattrmclaren)

Comment: Where would I put strpos(strtolower($concentration['name']), 'business') != -1

Comment: Updated the answer! And it actually should be `!== false`... my head was in AS3/JS last night.

Answer (score 0):

You want a function that will find a specific value on a specific field in the array,

```
function arraySearch($key, $value, $array){
  $flag = FALSE;
  foreach($array as $result){
    if(arraySearch($key, $value, $result)){
      $flag = TRUE
    }elseif(isset($result[$key] && $result[$key] == $value){
      $flag = TRUE;
    }
  }
  return $flag
}
```

to improve performance rather than setting $flag to true, you could return true as it will stop the execution of the function and prevent it from continuing to search the array.

Call it like so

```
foreach($fqlResult as $result){
  if(arraySearch('concentration', 'Business Administration', $result)){
    //You have found a user you are looking for, echo $result['name'] or do what you want with the result. 
  }
}
```